# Automating Windows Password Generation support in C#(.net)

Tags: c#, .net, google-compute-engine

As we can see from below link that we have support for retrieving Password for google VM using Java and Python with help of its inbuilt library. where we can fetch password and access VM using RDP.
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/windows/automate-pw-generation
But we dont have any library support to do same in .net.
We are developing application in .net to create/starting/stopping/deleting google VM . But we are not able to access that VM using RDP without having that password.

Its highly appreciated, if anyone will guide to do same for retrieving google VM  password using .net application.

Comment: Have you considered using the mentioned gcloud command line tool as a workaround? (i.e. run this tool from your c# application)

Comment: That's an *example script* that shows you how to use some API calls to reset the password. Did you check Google's *.NET* SDK?

Comment: No, we tried this as this one will not work. We are trying to make it generic, we have created application where using REST API(s), we can create a VM over GCP by passinf dynamic parameter for different user account. So we virtually dont have user name password for any GCP account based on access token only we play over GCP. So in this scenario, we cant access gcloud command line tool or anything. We want some sort of REST API information with valid access token , we can reset password for any Google VM.

Answer (score 1):

There's a workaround that seems to work, using a start-up powershell script:

```
private static string GetNewLocalUserScript(string userName, string password, bool isAdministrator)
{
    var createUserScript = $"New-LocalUser \"{userName}\" -Password (\"{password}\" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force) -FullName \"{userName}\"";

    if (isAdministrator)
    {
        createUserScript += $" \r\nAdd-LocalGroupMember -Group \"Administrators\" -Member \"{userName}\"";
    }

    return createUserScript;
}
```

Then you need to set this as a start-up script when you create a new VM instance in its metadata:

```
var metadata = new Metadata
{
    Items = new List<Metadata.ItemsData>(),
};

if (parameter.Accounts != null)
{
    foreach (var account in parameter.Accounts)
    {
        metadata.Items.Add(new Metadata.ItemsData
        {
            Key = "windows-startup-script-ps1",
            Value = GetNewLocalUserScript(account.Username, account.Password, account.IsAdministrator),
        });
    }
}

var instance = new Instance()
{
    Name = parameter.Name, 
    Metadata = metadata,
    ....
}
```

I know it's a late answer, but it may help some people. This doesn't use Google's mechanism of auto-generating a password and retrieving it, but it is rather useful when you have to set specific passwords for those user accounts.